# How can I make this For loop work without initializing it?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm very very new and trying random easy stuff to get a grasp on my skills. This for loop is supposed to take how many days into the year your halfbirthday is, and figure out which month that day belongs to. Clunky I know but this is simply for practice. DaysIntoYear represents how many days into the year the persons actual birthday is.

The idea is to take the number of days into the year and one by one subtract out the length of all the months. When it gets below 0, we know that's the month I am looking for and I can take that int and pass it thru another function to get the String version of the month name. it wants me to initialize the variable Month but doing so breaks my equations. Initializing it as either 0 or 365 does not work. How can I make this work using just concepts laid out here? Again, I am very new and just trying to work with simple methods and for loops right now. But maybe a Do-While loop would work better? Let me know.

```
public static int GetHalfDay (int Birthday)
{
    int monthLength[] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int YearLength = 365; int HalfYear = 183;
    int HalfDay;
    int x = 1 ;

    if (Birthday >= 183)
    {
        HalfDay = Birthday - HalfYear;
    }
    else if (Birthday < 183)
    {
        HalfDay = Birthday + HalfYear;
    }

    for (int i=0; x > 0 ; i++)
    {
        x = YearLength - monthLength[i];

    }

   return x; 
}
```

Comment: When I copied your code, my IDE complained that _Year cannot be resolved to a variable_

Comment: you do understand that in your code, you have an endless loop? the condition doesn't change during execution, so either it executes never, or always. I have no idea what exactly you are trying to do, but "trying randomly stuff" is not a good way to "improve your skills". It's a good way to get confused

Comment: @Abra which doesn't mean it can't be an instance variable

Comment: @Stultuske shouldn't code posted in a question be a [mcve] ? I was indicating to the OP that the code he posted does not compile. So are you saying that I should assume `Year` is an instance variable and modify the OP's code to make it compile?

Comment: @Abra I'm quite aware of that rule, but the OP stating that it's a runtime issue does suggest the variable exists. Or, another likely reason is that the OP meant YearLength. We can look at it from both ways, and still come with an answer. In this example, it is possible to work it out without having the entire class.

Comment: I updated to clean it up a little bit. I need to know what to do with variable x. What do I put there to make it work?

Comment: Thank you for correcting the code you posted in your question. So if my birthday is today (April 8th), then I would pass 99 to your `GetHalfDay()` method?

Comment: That's correct Abra. The idea is to then calculate the day of your half birthday which is day 273. Then I want to take 273 and subtract 31, then 28, then 31, etc until the value gets below 0. When it gets below 0, I can have the loop stop, take how many times the loop ran, and use that integer to determine which month the loop stopped in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static int getHalfDay(int birthday) {
    int monthLength[] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    int yearLength = (birthday + 183) % 365;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; yearLength > 0 ; i++) {
        yearLength -= monthLength[i];
    }
    return i - 1;
}
```

I suggest stepping through it using a debugger to understand how it works.

Comment: Very impressive. Thank you, I will take some time to understand how this works. I still don't get why mine needed me to initialize that variable, but I will take your code and learn from it, thank you

Comment: Very clever using the mod (%) to determine the days in for the half birthday in just one line of code. I have much to learn